# Complicated list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Im trying to build a list through list comprehension in python.
What I have so far, and it works:

```
modified_list = [
    {id: metadata}
    for id, metadata in new_resource_map.items()
    if id not in old_resource_map or metadata["lastModified"] != old_resource_map[id]["lastModified"] 
]
```

My list called: `modified_list`

Every item in it is dictionary `{id: metadata}`

I want to add one more thing and it will look like that:

```
modified_list = [
    {id: metadata}
    for id, metadata in new_resource_map.items()
    if id not in old_resource_map or metadata["lastModified"] != old_resource_map[id]["lastModified"] **or
       metadata["infer_tags"] != old_resource_map[id]["infer_tags"]**
]
```

The problem is what the last part:

```
or   metadata["infer_tags"] != old_resource_map[id]["infer_tags"]
```

The problem is not all of the files have that field ("infer_tags").

I wanna do this last thing only after I check if this field is existing.

Is anyone know to do that?

Comment: "I wanna do this last thing only after I check if this field is existing. Is anyone know to do that?" This has nothing to do with list comprehensions. How would you handle the check normally?

Comment: not all `metadata` have it or not all `old_resource_map[id]` ? or both ?

Comment: From what I understand you need to add a check if this field exist before doing the logic

Comment: not all metadata have the field "infer_tags"

Comment: You may need [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get).

Comment: if key is missing what's the logic to do ?

Comment: If the key is missing than the logic is like before: modified_list = [
    {id: metadata}
    for id, metadata in new_resource_map.items()
    if id not in old_resource_map or metadata["lastModified"] != old_resource_map[id]["lastModified"] 
]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as [Mechanic Pig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17980931/mechanic-pig) suggests:

```
    if id not in old_resource_map or metadata["lastModified"] != old_resource_map[id]["lastModified"] or
       metadata.get("infer_tags", np.nan) != old_resource_map[id].get("infer_tags", np.nan)
```

Note that the default values used in the get() calls must not be valid values for infer_tags fields for this to be reliable.

Comment: np.nan seems better for default i.e. `metadatda metadata.get("infer_tags", np.nan) != old_resource_map[id].get("infer_tags", np.nan)`, since np.nan also has the property that `np.nan != np.nan` evaluates to  True.

Comment: Thanks DarrylG, that is better! Answer updated to include np.nan.